# How to stop heartbeat service rather using kill command?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, heartbeat, metricbeat

I am not getting the way to stop heartbeat service of ELK and using kill command to force stop the heartbeat service.

Could observe Killing heartbeat service directly creating confusion in the background.

to start :
./heartbeat -c heartbeat.yml -e
to stop ?

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

I do it, basically delegate the task to a process control system like http://supervisord.org/index.html

You create the config file for the process:

```
[program:foo]
command=/bin/cat
```

and then you will start/stop [like](http://supervisord.org/running.html#running-supervisor) `supervisordctl stop foo` supervisor will do the job depending on the configs you set in the supervisor.conf. Other advantages if that the program crashes due to a critic error, it will be automatically started if you configured in the file to do so.